# PostgreSQL - Column view_definition from information_schema.views is null

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the following script create schema and grant permissions

```sql
CREATE USER admin_user  WITH PASSWORD 'ExtremStr0ngPassw0rd';
CREATE USER normal_user WITH PASSWORD 'Str0ngPassw0rd';

CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC;

ALTER SCHEMA my_schema OWNER TO admin_user;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "my-db" TO admin_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "my-db" TO admin_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA my_schema TO admin_user;

GRANT CONNECT, TEMP, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "my-db" TO normal_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO normal_user;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO normal_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER admin_user IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO normal_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER admin_user IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO normal_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER admin_user IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO normal_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER admin_user IN SCHEMA information_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO normal_user;
```

Then the admin user creates a table and view

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_schema.test_1
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    text_value TEXT
    CONSTRAINT test_1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE VIEW my_schema.view_1 as SELECT * FROM my_schema.test_1;
```

After that, I login as normal_user

I can do a select on the VIEW `my_schema.view_1`.

What I can't do as normal_user to see the view_definition column on views in information_schema.

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
```

The column is always null.

Has anyone any idea which grant is missing or can explain why the normal_user can't see the view_definition?

Comment: 1) [views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-views.html): *Only those views are shown that the current user has access to (by way of being the owner or having some privilege).* 2) [ALTER DEFAULT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html): *ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be applied to objects created in the future.*. 3) In `psql` run `\dp my_schema.view_1` to see what privileges you actually granted.